# Can't create replies to some existing youtube comments

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a software, which allows you to create a reply to a comment on your youtube video. Therefore I use the youtube API v3 [comments.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) method.

`POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/comments?part=id%2Csnippet&access_token=[access_token]
{
 "snippet": {
  "parentId": "parentId",
  "textOriginal": "test message"
 }
}`

Most of the time the requests are successful. But for some comments I can't create replies this way. The API always returns:

`{
     "error": {
         "errors": [
             {
                 "domain": "youtube.comment",
                 "reason": "processingFailure",
                 "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>comment</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid.",
                 "locationType": "other",
                 "location": "body"
             }
         ],
         "code": 400,
         "message": "The API server failed to successfully process the request. While this can be a transient error, it usually indicates that the requests input is invalid. Check the structure of the <code>comment</code> resource in the request body to ensure that it is valid."
     }
}`

I'm using a valid access token and the parentId is valid, too, because I can retrieve it through the API.
I took a look at the successful and failing requests, but didn't find any difference. So I assume that the request input isn't invalid as it is mentioned in the error message.
In my opinion this error isn't a transient error, because the same requests are still failing after some days.

I also tried to create a reply on such a comment through the API Explorer but the result was the same.

Does anyone have the same problems or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of some of the comments for which you are unable to create a reply? Along with the video ID, of course. You're using similar comment resource structure in your request body each time you try to make a reply, right?

Comment: Yes, the structure of my failing POST reply requests are always the same as the successful ones.For example, I can't create a reply to this comment id "z13rgftjgw3bulyou04ccfnbjofztxg54yo0k" on this video id "Xq7k5Ti2mGA". Neither through an API request from my software nor through the API Explorer directly.

Comment: When I use the CommentThreads.list call to get more information about that comment (`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet&id=z13rgftjgw3bulyou04ccfnbjofztxg54yo0k&key=[API_KEY_HERE]`), it says `"canReply": false` in the items section. It seems unusual that it would give you that `processingFailure` error instead of the `operationNotSupported` [error](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert#errors).

Comment: That would be the expected error yes. Do you know why I'm not able to insert a reply to some comments on a video, when it works for others. Creating a reply for this comment ID "z13tjxdqnuygy1lga04cilcqxqipg1zbtbs" on the same video (Xq7k5Ti2mGA) will work with an access token of the owner of the video. Is this a personal user setting?
And do you know any workaround for this problem, when the error message is not reliable?

Comment: When I look at the video comments, the comment with ID `z13tjxdqnuygy1lga04cilcqxqipg1zbtbs` has a "reply" option under it, while the comment with ID `z13rgftjgw3bulyou04ccfnbjofztxg54yo0k` does not. It's possible that the user posted the comment via their Google+ page and disabled replies to their posts.

Comment: You are right. I managed to reproduce this behavior. Did not know that you can disable replies for your own comments. But for this issue the `operationNotSupported` error should definitely be thrown. Thanks a lot @not_a_bot

Comment: No problem, would you mind accepting this solution if I post it as an answer? That way, other people can see that we were able to figure out why it wasn't working.

Comment: Of course I will do that.

Comment: Great, I'll post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I go to the video and look at the comments directly, the comment with ID `z13tjxdqnuygy1lga04cilcqxqipg1zbtbs` has a "reply" option under it, while the comment with ID `z13rgftjgw3bulyou04ccfnbjofztxg54yo0k` does not. It seems that the user posted the comment via their Google+ page and disabled replies to their posts.